# Script Kiddie attempts triggering Rails URI::InvalidURIError - how to filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I just launched a production Rails app (on Heroku) on a long-existing domain and, of course, now that it's facing the wide open web, I'm picking up all the flotsam and jetsam of the attempted script kiddies.

I have any exceptions that get thrown emailed to me and I've managed to catch (rescue_from) all the standard errors, but this keeps coming through a few times a day:

```
An URI::InvalidURIError occurred in #:

bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.myapp.com/assets/,data:n,complete:function(e,t)
{r&&u.each(r,o||[e.responseText,t,e])}}).done(function(e){o=arguments,u
vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'


-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

 * URL       : http://myapp.com/assets/,data:n,complete:function(e,t)
{r&&u.each(r,o||[e.responseText,t,e])}}).done(function(e){o=arguments,u.html(i?v(
 * IP address: 195.241.58.105
 * Parameters: {"v("=>nil, "path"=>"assets/,data:n,complete:function(e,t){r&&u.each(r,o||
[e.responseText,t,e])}}).done(function(e){o=arguments,u", "format"=>"html(i"}
 * Rails root: /app
 * Timestamp : 2013-02-26 16:53:51 UTC
```

So from my untrained eye, this looks like script kiddies attempting to try for some sort of vulnerability (or?)

My questions:

1)  This is one area where I'm not sure how far the "rails magic" goes -- do I need to do anything?  I don't really like that outside forces are able to cause an exception in my app just from the request.  Should I be rescuing the URI::InvalidURIError exception and just throwing a 404?  Is there anything more I should be doing?  Does this happen to everyone?

2)  Is something misconfigured or is this just standard "stock production" behavior for an app?  I'm running Rails 3.2.12 (latest patched version as of this posting).

Thanks in advance for any advice!

EDIT:  Adding some more details about the requests, as Christian pointed out below, might not be script kiddies?  Either way, I'm curious.

2nd request:

```
An URI::InvalidURIError occurred in #:

bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.myapp.com/assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&
(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&
(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt
 vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'


-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

 * URL       : http://myapp.com/assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&
(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&
(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt.exec(e)||[
 * IP address: 217.16.182.42
 * Parameters: {"path"=>"assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&
(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt", "format"=>"exec(e)||["}
 * Rails root: /app
 * Timestamp : 2013-02-27 18:37:20 UTC
```

3rd request:

```
An URI::InvalidURIError occurred in #:

 bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.myapp.com/assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&
(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&
(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt
 vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'


-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

 * URL       : http://myapp.com/assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&
(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&
(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt.exec(e)||[
 * IP address: 62.141.42.107
 * Parameters: {"path"=>"assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&
(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt", "format"=>"exec(e)||["}
 * Rails root: /app
 * Timestamp : 2013-02-27 20:56:25 UTC
```

Comment: Funny you include their IP address :D

Comment: Heh - well they don't deserve anonymity, that's for sure ;)

Comment: Netherlands, Koninklijke KPN N.V. - looks like a person, not a VPN. If the guy was actually trying to do something to you, it would come in more frequently and not at a frequency of like once a day, and he would probably try to anonymise himself. Are the IPs different each request?

Comment: I hadn't actually looked for a pattern but went back to the emails and checked.  3 different requests, all in a row, from 3 different IPs.  Each batch of requests was sent 3 times -- all the same requests and IPs each time.  Weird.  I'll update the original question with more details (just because I'm curious if anyone has an idea what this is).

Comment: I found this query, and I also not keen on the RoutingError messages and exceptions triggering problems.  What I'd like is a list of common script-kiddie attempts (like /cgi, /admin/config.php, /xmlrpc.php) and a way to tell my presentation-tier or web interface to just blackhole requests from any IP that makes them.

I consider writing such a module.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that code in my production.log

```
GET "/assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt.exec(e)||["
```

Rails 3.2.13 dealt with it with `Completed 406 Not Acceptable`

Answer (score 0):

I found the same in my logs but in november 2012:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/&&!yt.test(e)&&(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt.exec(e)||["):`